# how to set div inside div in columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to have this [result](http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/byfm2/)

With **only** two `DIVS` like the code below

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/2gM2d/1/) to work

**EDIT**

Based on `Sowmya` answer (which is wrong) **please notice that I need the numbers to be in the same orders**

```
.content{
    padding:10px;     
    width:282px;
    height:90px;
    border:solid 1px #444;
}
.item{
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    width:50px;
    border:solid 1px #999;
}

<div class="content">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>  
    <div class="item">12</div>  
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to use CSS3's Columns. (Sorry I had to play around with the widths and heights) =)

```
.content{
    padding:10px;     
    width:285px;
    height:105px;
    border:solid 1px #444;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
}
.item{
    padding:5px;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    width:50px;
    border:solid 1px #999;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2gM2d/45/

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have upvoted it.. Is your solution working with IE ?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the result using the CSS3 `flex` property.

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/luvoqovi/1/edit)**.

```
.content{
    padding:10px;     
    width:282px;
    height:105px; /*Height need to change*/
    border:solid 1px #444;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.item{
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    width:50px;
    border:solid 1px #999;
}
```

Comment: `flex` isn't supported on latest Safari yet.  I think mine is better.  See mine... =)

Comment: IE11 suppoert it  and  IE10 required prefix . see more for info. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my choice goes for @josephnvu answer as it is more browser compatible. I have upvoted your answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` to `.item`

```
.item{
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    width:50px;
    border:solid 1px #999;
    float:left
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2gM2d/5/)**

Comment: that's what i was thinking.  the numbers go from left to right and not up and down

Answer (score -1):

Change width in `.content` class to `134px` and add `float:left` in `.item` class

Here is a fiddle for this [**Click Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2gM2d/26/)

Comment: <br class='clear' /> is added after each two div to retain the height of the container. Else you need to change the height as per your requirement.

Comment: Read the question :) I need the numbers in the SAME orders